# Creating Chloramines

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, everyday-chemistry, ph, corrosion

I'm currently conducting some testing related to indoor pool environments.
Here I believe, airborne chloramines are responsible for *stress corrosion cracking* in austenitic stainless steels.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to generate the said chloramines for testing purposes.My setup so far includes a sealed container in which I can suspend samples over hydrous chlorine (~ pH 7.4) similar to pool areas. This container also has a clear lid with reflective panels aimed at it, to act similar to a box-type solar cooker (adding heat to increase humidity and accelerate corrosion).

From my basic research chloramines are measured as free (elemental) chlorine plus ammonia compounds (urea/carbamide). In my basic (pardon the pun) understanding, I thought the addition of hydrogen peroxide (urea) or Cloudy Ammonia would create chloramine(s). However, I've now found [a thread](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/161945/does-hydrogen-peroxide-remove-chloramine-from-water) that states hydrogen peroxide REMOVES chloramines from water.

Send help! (I know chloramines in pools are created by bodily fluids, please don't make me sh!t in a bucket at work...)

Comment: Sorry I can not help with your queston, but what you mean by _cloudy ammonia_?

Comment: 'Cloudy' ammonia is an off-the-shelf product used for cleaning purposes. Honestly have no idea what percentage "ammonia" or how it works as a solution. For the purposes of this test, we trying to make things corrode, so a little rough-and-ready is acceptable, so long as we know we've got some of the right gasses going.

Comment: Keep an eye on safety: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/is-mixing-ammonia-and-bleach-spray-in-the-same-parcel-of-air-considerably-danger ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47121/mixing-bleach-and-ammonia/126824 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/161945/does-hydrogen-peroxide-remove-chloramine-from-water/162006

Comment: @PAEP https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-ammonia-and-vs-cloudy-ammonia/amp/

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out, whilst not a complete answer it's got all the important bits. [This summary](http://www.hydroinstruments.com/files/Basic%20Chemistry%20of%20Chlorination.pdf) of chlorine action in pools has really pulled my admittedly simple research together. Looks like I just need to get some aqueous ammonia and we should be off to a good start.

[image: Chloramine Production]

Seems like I was barking up the wrong tree on the Hydrogen Peroxide front. Or I've just confused myself and they're kind of the same (still unsure how 'urea' fits in TBH)